# Why does pressure "put people on streets"?

Tags: song-lyrics, queen

> Pressure pushing down on me
>   Pressing down on you no man ask for
>   Under pressure that brings a building down
>   Splits a family in two
>   Puts people on streets

In what sense does pressure "put people on streets", and why does it do that? Is this referring to "the man on the street" and implying that people are either going about the "daily grind" because of pressure, or that people are about to "crack" under the pressure of the daily grind?

The later line

> Insanity laughs under pressure we're breaking

seems to suggest the latter interpretation.

Or is there a completely different interpretation entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I interpret it, the pressure of the daily grind is literally tearing people apart. It breaks buildings, it breaks families (likely speaking of divorce, here - the pressure getting so great that it chips away at the family until they can't take it and they divorce, or otherwise become estranged from each other), and it breaks people.

Basically, this song is speaking about the extreme pressures of modern life - the daily grind and this whole idea of having to have the most and be the best and richest and work the hardest, which can take a great toll on people, to the point where it can cause people to fall into poverty, and thus lose their homes and end up living on the streets.

The chorus emphasizes this idea of the pressure of the world and of life, and how no one wants to be a part of it, but there is no escaping it:

"It's the terror of knowing what the world is about
Watching some good friends screaming
'Let me out'"

Once people realize the stress that just trying to keep your ahead above water in modem society entails, it becomes this self serving endless circle, where you can't get ahead and the pressure of knowing that makes it harder to get ahead, so eventually you are so far behind that you can potentially end up on the streets in extreme poverty.